# Can't seem to get sudo working under NixOS

Tags: nixos

The title (embarassing as it is) says it all. Some context first:

I'm running NixOS using a custom ISO on Vultr.

Timeframe of attempts:

- `which sudo` shows no sudo
- Installed `sudo` using `nix-env -i sudo`
- Then, when I tried to `sudo ...`, I see `sudo: /home/agam/.nix-profile/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`
- `sudo su` didn't work for the same reason
- Okay, I uninstalled it (`nix-env --uninstall sudo`)
- Thought hmm, maybe I'm supposed to install it as root?
- So, `su` and then repeat the install
- Now when I try to `sudo ...`, I see `sudo: /nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`
  (so the same error as before, with a different path)
- As a last resort, try a hammer, and kudos to NixOS for stopping me:

```
[root@nixos:/home/agam]# chmod 4755 /nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/sudo
chmod: changing permissions of '/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/sudo': Read-only file system
```

Any clues on what's going on here?

Some possible options I see here are:
1. The custom ISO that Vultr provided was ... missing something
2. Some fundamentally different ways that `sudo` is supposed to work in NixOS
3. I'm missing something very basic in how to go about using Nix (most likely!)

Some details:

```
[agam@nixos:~]$ nixos-version
18.09.1534.d45a0d7a4f5 (Jellyfish)

[agam@nixos:~]$ which sudo
/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin/sudo

[agam@nixos:~]$ nix-channel --list
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-18.09
```

(*Note*: originally posted at StackOverflow, was recommended to ask here instead!)

Answer (score 1):

As NixOS is configured completely declaritiveley, there should be only one place where sudo is switched on and off: Your NixOS config (which probably lives in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`).

The option [`security.sudo.enable`](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#security.sudo.) should be `true` by default, but maybe you import a module, that overrides the default? Setting it to `true` explicitly should shine some light on this.